# How to increase width between two bar in highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The bar chart demo is here,

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lazybios/n5gob39v/)

I want to increase the width between different bars, What configuration should I set ? please give me some advice. thks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase width between two bar in highcharts.js you can use groupPadding,

API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.groupPadding

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6j3y54na/2/

```
groupPadding: 0.2
```

If you want to increase gap between bars in same group then you can use pointPadding

API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointPadding

Answer (score 1):

Use [pointWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointWidth) property, a pixel value specifying a fixed width for each column or bar:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'percent',
        pointWidth: 5
    }
},
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/6j3y54na/)**

Answer (score 0):

pointWidth is the parameter to set the width for bar width .Refer this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5gob39v/6/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            marginLeft: 50,
            marginBottom: 90
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'percent', pointWidth: 4
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
        }]
    });
});
```